# How do i create my own datatype variable in VISUAL BASIC?

Tags: vb.net, binary

**I want to create my own varaible that hold only two value 0 and 1**

Comment: DIM something AS BOOLEAN ...?

Comment: NO,For example byte is a smallest varaible in visual basic.it holds 0 to 256 whole number values (means 256). As you know 1 byte = (8 bit) i want to create varaible that holds only two numbers 0 and 1 and it would be equal to 2 bits one for 1 and one for 0.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create any such data type in Visual Basic .NET

Comment: Assembly, C, c++ can do those easily.

Comment: Why do you want to create a datatype that is already available in any of the language ?

Comment: The nearest you can get is to pack multiple binary values into a byte using bitwise logic.